# loop to access multiple files in a directory

Tags: loops, directory, stata

I have a directory with 31 files on which I have to create some variables, then join them. I am trying through a loop but I can not. Could someone help me ?

```
cd "my dir"
local allfiles: dir "my dir" files "*.dta"
clear

foreach f in `allfiles' {

  use `f'
  egen string_id = concat(ido idd)
  sort string_id
   by string_id: gen first = _n==1

gen id = sum(first)
drop first

sort year id
 by year id: egen Value=sum(value)
  by year id: egen Quantity=sum(quantity)

save `mydata', replace
 append using `mydata' 
}
```

Comment: I have marked up your code.  Please remember to prefix each line with 4 spaces.

Comment: As your code makes explicit, you don't really want to `join` them, but `append` them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your report

> I am trying through a loop but I can not

is not a useful one.

Remember to specify the exact problem you face, i.e., what you get, what you expect, and if not obvious, why they are not the same.

Below is working code, assuming you have two copies of the built-in **auto** dataset (load it using `sysuse auto`), in the example directory.

```
clear
set more off

// example directory with auto1.dta and auto2.dta
cd "/home/roberto/Desktop/stata_tests/"
local allfiles: dir "`c(pwd)'" files "*.dta"

// create empty dataset to initiate appending
tempfile mydata
save "`mydata'", emptyok

foreach f in `allfiles' {

    // load data and do whatever
    use "`f'", clear
    gen source = "`f'"

    // append first, then save
    append using "`mydata'"
    save "`mydata'", replace
}

// check
keep make source
sort make source
list in 1/16, sepby(make)
```

The output:

```
. list in 1/16, sepby(make)

     +---------------------------+
     | make               source |
     |---------------------------|
  1. | AMC Concord     auto1.dta |
  2. | AMC Concord     auto2.dta |
     |---------------------------|
  3. | AMC Pacer       auto1.dta |
  4. | AMC Pacer       auto2.dta |
     |---------------------------|
  5. | AMC Spirit      auto1.dta |
  6. | AMC Spirit      auto2.dta |
     |---------------------------|
  7. | Audi 5000       auto1.dta |
  8. | Audi 5000       auto2.dta |
     |---------------------------|
  9. | Audi Fox        auto1.dta |
 10. | Audi Fox        auto2.dta |
     |---------------------------|
 11. | BMW 320i        auto1.dta |
 12. | BMW 320i        auto2.dta |
     |---------------------------|
 13. | Buick Century   auto1.dta |
 14. | Buick Century   auto2.dta |
     |---------------------------|
 15. | Buick Electra   auto1.dta |
 16. | Buick Electra   auto2.dta |
     +---------------------------+
```

See also `ssc describe fs` and `ssc describe filelist`.